# "No definition found"

Tags: ios, dictionary

I recently restored my iPhone 5 from backup, and noticed that my dictionary always gives the message "No definition found" (although this could have started earlier and I just didn't notice until now). I tried selecting Manage from the bottom left of the empty dictionary message, then deleting and re-adding a dictionary; however, I still get the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Apple Support discussion, [iPhone 5, my 'define' word feature no longer is an option. How can I get it back?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4611162?tstart=0), suggests the following:

> 1. Go to **Settings > General > International > Language**
> 2. Change the language to one of Apples supported languages like Spanish.
> 3. Go to your notepad, type "test", press hold, select the word, and click the "define" that now appears.
> 4. This will tell you there is no current dictionary, and prompt for one to be downloaded.
> 5. Assure you are on a stable Wi-Fi network, and hit download.
> 6. Once complete, go back to your language settings and switch back to your native language.
> 7. Enjoy your dictionary feature without having to "reset" your phone.

Comment: 4 is not necessarily correct. In my case, there was a current dictionary. I deleted it, added it back, and added another one (just in case). That worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just went into General -> Language & Region and in the preferred language order hit 'Add Language' (I selected French because this was a language I didn't already have). It then asked me which language I wanted to keep as my preferred default and I selected 'English'. It did its updating thing & all was well. My definitions returned.

Answer (score -1):

1. Highlight ("Select"), and try to "Define," a word.
2. If it comes up with "No definition found," click on "Manage" (lower left corner).
3. Download your preferred dictionary from the Apple Cloud (by tapping on the appropriate cloud and arrow symbol).

Comment: Please note that the question specifies this had already been tried, and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

When you define a word and the no definition comes up. On the bottom left is "manage". Click that then chose a dictionary! Then try it again and you will see definitions!